# Equivalent method to "Reset to Match Style"

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am looking for a c# method equivalent to the "Reset to Match Style" function when you right click on a Chart. In fact I change Datalabels font size in my code but the font size is always 18. The good font size is applied when I use the "Reset to Match Style" function" but I need to do it in code.

Thanks in advance,

Leep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days of developement, I have solved my issue.
It was not obvious because the Api is not clear with that. You have to use the Paste method of your chart Object which is inherited from _Chart.

Here is the Api link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.paste(v=office.14).aspx